# HorizontalScrollView with AutoSize textView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout where textview will automatically resize the text inside it but after getting to minimum size it should start scrolling like in google calculator. [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WsCz.jpg).

By simply putting TextView in HorizontalScrollView after whole width is filled it doesn't decrease the size of the text. [upper text view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOAvp.jpg)

My code:

```xml
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:background="@color/nHistoryBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHistory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/histMinSz"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/histMaxSz"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: What if you set the `android:layout_width` of your horizontal scrollview to `wrap_content` ?

Comment: @Mirco0 width to wrap_content has no effect and height to wrap_content will set the textsize to min text size

Answer (score 0):

### Setting up TextView autosize

You can use either framework or support library to set up the autosizing of `TextView` programmatically or in `XML`. To set the `XML` attributes, you can also use the Properties window in Android Studio.

There are three ways you can set up the autosizing of `TextView`:

- Default
- Granularity
- Preset Sizes

##### Default

Default setting lets the autosizing of `TextView` scale uniformly on horizontal and vertical axes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

##### Granularity

You can define a range of minimum and maximum text sizes and a dimension that specifies the size of each step. The `TextView` scales uniformly in a range between the minimum and maximum size attributes. Each increment occurs as per the step size set in the granularity attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

##### Preset Sizes

Preset sizes lets you specify all the values that the `TextView` picks when automatically auto-sizing text.

Set the `autoSizeText` attribute to either none or uniform. none is a default value and uniform lets `TextView` scale uniformly on horizontal and vertical axes.

Set the `autoSizePresetSizes` attribute to an array of preset sizes. To access the array as a resource, define the array in the `res/values/arrays.xml` file.

```
<resources>
  <array name="autosize_text_sizes">
    <item>10sp</item>
    <item>12sp</item>
    <item>20sp</item>
    <item>40sp</item>
    <item>100sp</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes" />
```

For more details about `Autosizing TextViews`, You can follow [Google's official Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

Comment: No the question isn't about resizing the textView as you can see in second gif that i have a textView which is not in HorizontalScrollView and can resize it's text. The question is about resizing text in HorizontalScrollView as you can see in 1st animation of google calculator